# Exporting business contacts from google to outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, export

I exported my Google contacts and imported them into Outlook at people.live.com.  The contacts with a first & last name transferred without a problem.  But my business contacts (those that don't have a first or last name field populated) did not.  I'm running Windows 8.1 on a PC.

Is there way to export / import those contacts automatically or do I have to populate the first OR last name field in order to have the export/import function work?

Or is there some other way to import them into Outlook?

Thanks.